# How did Gollum follow the Fellowship through Lothlórien without being caught?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

Lothlórien was guarded well. How did Gollum follow the Fellowship through Lórien without being caught by the Elves as the Fellowship was?

> The Dwarf breathes so loud, we could have shot him in the dark.

Where was Gollum and what did he do while the Fellowship dwelt in Caras Galadhon?

Comment: Because he's sneaky and animalistic

Comment: Gollum is a hobbit, not a dwarf.  And he's had centuries of practice at stealth.  When you live in a cave full of orcs with nothing to protect you but a ring that makes you invisible (but notably *not* any quieter), you learn to be pretty sneaky to survive.  Also, if *Rings of Power* is canon (which is of course debatable), Hobbits in general have been so good at stealth that nobody else knew they existed for centuries, as there's no records of them before well into the 3rd Age.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The Dwarf quote is from Haldir who said it to Gimli. Gollum wasn't talked about.

Comment: @IkemNoren That was my point.  The elves could hear Gimli in the dark, because he's a dwarf and dwarves evidently suck at stealth.  Gollum is much better at keeping quiet.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Rings of Power is NOT canon

Comment: @DarrelHoffman how many centuries, and when?  Because (1) hobbits evolved from humans, and (2) people have hunted stealthy animals for a long, long time.

Comment: @NigelFds Yeah, I knew I'd get pushback on that point, which is why I hedged on it.  At best it's a pretty egregious retcon.  But it would make sense, from an evolutionary standpoint, that hobbits have been around a lot longer than previously thought.  It would take many thousands of years of separation for humans and hobbits to have diverged so thoroughly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems that Gollum does not actually enter Lothlórien - as you note the elves guarded its borders very well.

Gollum picked up the fellowship's trail in Moria, and followed them to the border of Lothlórien, marked by the Silverlode river. On January the 15th, the night before the fellowship entered Lothlórien he attempted to approach Frodo by climbing the tree where he was resting, but Haldir scared him away:

> Something was now climbing slowly, and its breath came like a soft
> hissing through closed teeth. Then coming up, close to the stem, Frodo
> saw two pale eyes. They stopped and gazed upward unwinking. Suddenly
> they turned away, and a shadowy figure slipped round the trunk of the
> tree and vanished.
>
> Immediately afterwards Haldir came climbing swiftly up through the
> branches. ‘There was something in this tree that I have never seen
> before,’ he said. ‘It was not an orc. It fled as soon as I touched the
> tree-stem. It seemed to be wary, and to have some skill in trees, or I
> might have thought that it was one of you hobbits.

The next day the company crossed the river, were blindfolded, and were brought to Galadriel. Gollum does not follow them however. In *The Fellowship of the Ring* we lose track of him after the incident in the flet, until the Fellowship leave Lothlórien, and he starts to follow them again on February the 16th as they go down the Anduin in boats. What was he doing during that month?

According to the time-scheme given in *The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion* by Hammond and Scull, Gollum was waiting outside Lothlórien, but was captured by Uglúk, and under torture revealed that hobbits from the Shire were among the party that had escaped into Lothlórien. Gollum then managed to escape, and continued prowling the woods until he saw the departure of the fellowship.

This information is derived from the timeline scheme that Tolkien prepared (archived as Marquette MSS 4/2/18). Thanks to commenter David Roberts, we can confirm this information from *The Chronology of The Lord of the Rings* itself, which [has now been published](https://muse.jhu.edu/issue/48264) in the Vol 19 supplement of Tolkien Studies (edited by William Cloud Hicklin). The sequence of events is:

> January 15 S[unday] | Gollum dogs the Co[mpan]y and climbs up flet.
> Then escapes and haunts west-borders of Lórien.
>
> 17 Tu. | For many days Gollum lurks near Lórien, moving slowly towards
> the southern borders.
>
> 24 Tu. | Gollum captured by Uglúk, but escapes after revealing that
> Hobbits of Shire were with Gandalf, and enough is said to make Uglúk
> certain that Ring was with the Company.
>
> February 16 W. | Observes departure of Company and follows them.

Comment: Did the *Companion* just make that up, or is it based on something?

Comment: @OrangeDog It's a serious work of scholarship, so I do not think they just made it up. I do not have the original source material, but H&S give the origin as Tolkien's timeline scheme: "J. R. R. Tolkien, latest and only complete manuscript time-scheme for The Lord of the Rings (Marquette MSS 4/2/18) "

Comment: @Clara and the _Scheme_ is now published, so we don't just have to take H&S' word. I can dig out the entry in a little bit for you, if you like.

Comment: @Clara: here are the dates and descriptions: "January 15S[unday] | Gollum dogs the Co[mpan]y and climbs up flet. Then escapes and haunts west-borders of Lórien." "17 Tu | For many days Gollum lurks near Lórien, moving slowly towards the southern borders." "Tu. 24 | Gollum captured by Uglúk, but escapes after revealing that Hobbits of Shire were with Gandalf, and enough is said to make Uglúk certain that Ring was with the Company." "February W. 16 | Observes departure of Company and follows them."

Comment: @Clara I added a link to the actual publication

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - With regards to the scheme I think H&S and WCH are both equally reliable. However the orginal pages were all published in facsimile in *The Art of the Manuscript* so if you don't trust either of their transcriptions you can go there.

Comment: If people are worried about the canonicity of your source, **Appendix B of LotR itself** also has enough information to confirm the answer to the question. From 16 February 3019: *"Farewell to Lórien. Gollum in hiding on the west bank observes the departure."* Which suggests that he never got into Lórien himself but was in the right place to spot the Fellowship leaving.